# Passing the result to the jsp page after the servlet has been executed

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have an issue. When I click in a link the execution is passed to a servlet. Into this servlet there is the overridden `init()` that should be executed when the servlet starts. My question is how I can pass the element `CountriesList` to the jsp page `signup.jsp` ? If I were into the doGet() or doPost() functions, I could use `forward()` function but this is not the case. Any idea?

```
@Override
public void init()
            throws ServletException
{
        this.getServletContext().setAttribute("CountriesList", signUpBean.getContriesList());
}
```

EDIT

problem solved

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        request.setAttribute("CountriesList", signUpBean.getContriesList());

        String arg = "/signup.jsp";
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(arg);
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);               
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`init` is called when the `Servlet` instance is reused. But a `Servlet` instance might be created once and reused many times (each time invoking `doGet`, `doPost`...).

In essence: `init()` is for servlet initialization after instantiation, and nothing else. You process the request with the `doXXX` methods.

UPDATE:

To retrieve the data that you put in the `ServletContext`, for example in the `doGet` (or, in your example, `processRequest`), you just do

```
List<Country> countriesList = (CountriesList) getServletContext().getAttribute("CountriesList");
```

to retrieve the value.

You can also access `getServletContext()` from the JSP itself.

If you are using JSTL and you put a bean inside the `ServletContext`, it may also be retrieved as an "application scoped" bean. Not sure how it would behave with a `List` or array of beans, though.

Comment: In the following page https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/ecommerce/entity-session.html the init() function is used to get from db all category when the servlet is called

Comment: Ok I understood what you mean...above how I can fixed the problem.

Comment: What that code does is add the attribute to the `ServletContext`, which is like defining it as a variable that will live as long as the webapp.

Comment: @Mazzy - Thanks to you, I accidentally discovered the end-to-end Java EE tutorial that I was looking for. Any more like this tutorial ? Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just get the countries list from the `signUpBean` in the JSP page?

Comment: I think it is the best way because in this way I can leave to the servlet the job to handle the POST and GET requests.

Comment: Instead of passing an EJB, I would recommend executing the EJB logic (v.g. categoryFacade.getCountries()) in the Servlet and pass to the JSP only the results.

Comment: Yes. The rule of thumb is try to avoid putting logic in the JSPs.

Comment: @SJuan76  but My question is...after the page is loaded correctly showing all the countries list, I do a request to the same servlet. how can I handle the request? since there is already the code to retrieve countrylist, where should I place the code to handle the signup form? I should have a way to distinguish the code to handle the signup form and the code to retrieve country list